# Netbeans branding localization

Tags: java, netbeans, user-interface, internationalization

I have done branding of pice of my Netbeans application according this article [Link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/BrandingUpdaterSplash)

But I dont understand, how can I localize it? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relationship between the link you provided and the localization.

You can read the following articles in order to getting started with localization. You need resource bundles.

[Java Internationalization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/)

[Internationalization](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/int.html)

Comment: I can explain. I should use my "Captions" in NB standart windows and forms. I have done a new file with name *******.jar, and que of folders with the same names as package. I put there bundle. properties with my strings and it works fine. But I should do it for many languages. Thanks!